# doubles with commas/dots in webapi 2 uris

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

This URI:

```
http://localhost:50454/api/Bla/Get/50/-2
```

with this webapi controller action:

```
Route("Bla/{x:double}/{y:double}")]
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Bla([FromUri] double x, double y)
{
// ...
}
```

However, as soon as I start using something like this which contains a comma/dot:

```
http://localhost:50454/api/Bla/Get/50/-2.1
```

I get 404 error. Why is this? How can I fix this?

I understand now that I have to use:

```
http://localhost:50454/api/Bla/Get/50/-2.1/
```

However, can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a back slash at the end of your url it will work.

Like this given below

http://localhost:50454/api/Bla/Get/50/-2.1**/**